# Generate SWIG-Proxy for C-function with param "char**"

Tags: c#, c, swig

I try to generate a wrapper with SWIG for this C-Code:

```
extern APIKeyRef_t parse_api_key(char* p0, char** p1)
```

The second Parameter p1 gets generate by SWIG as a "SWIGTYPE_p_p_char" which is useless from C#. How do I tell SWIG to generate a "out string" or "ref string" Parameter here? I've read the docs of SWIG, but do only understand half of it. It might be an easy thing for SWIG-pros.

The method is automatically generated from a Go-function. "APIKeyRef_t" and "char*" are working perfectly - SWIG generates nice wrappers for them.

Thank you!

Comment: If you must work in C#, mark the code as unsafe, then you can use C type pointers.  Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types You can then call the unsafe code from the safe code.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this really helps me. How would I then provide a value to the C-function through P/Invoke/SWIG that gives me the ref/out-string in this case?

Comment: Is p1 and input or output parameter?

Comment: It should become a ref or out - meaning, the underlying c/go-function will create an unmanaged string and return it to me via this parameter.

Comment: No idea, anybody?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but have a look at how it is handled in Java.  https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/swig/Doc/Manual/Java.html#Java_converting_java_string_arrays  C# will be very similar.

Comment: Thanks for that hint - but I'm unable to get it transferred to C# as I do not really understand what's Happening there. Furthermore I'm confused that this Code tries to map char** to a string-Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in SWIG. I don't normally write much (read: any) C# and I tested this with Mono on Linux, so there's a fairly heavy caveat to my answer - you should validate its correctness carefully.

Anyway we can generate a wrapper that I'm reasonably happy is correct. SWIG (in most modes in most languages) generates wrappers in two parts. Some code, written in the language you're building a wrapper for (i.e. C# here) and also some C or C++.

By customising the C# entry point into the wrapper we can set the stage for our argument. Essentially we use this to pass an `IntPtr` (initialised to NULL) by reference into our C function. After the function call has happened we then use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to read the output String, which we now know the address of, back into the C# world as an output to our C# function.

Finally all that's left to do is clean up. This step depends on the semantics of the function we're calling - if we end up owning the string we need to free it once we've taken a copy. So if we don't own the string we mustn't free it. And if `FreeHGlobal` isn't the right way to free it you'll need to substitute an alternative.

```
%module test

%typemap(csin,pre="global::System.IntPtr tmp$csinput=global::System.IntPtr.Zero;",
              post="$csinput=global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(tmp$csinput);
                    global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tmp$csinput);") char **OUTPUT "ref tmp$csinput";
%typemap(cstype) char **OUTPUT "out string";

%typemap(imtype) char **OUTPUT "ref global::System.IntPtr"

%apply char **OUTPUT { char **outarg };

%{
#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
%}

%inline %{
void foobar(char **outarg) {
  fprintf(stderr, "In foobar: outarg is: %p\n", outarg);
  fprintf(stderr, "*outarg starts as: %p\n", *outarg); // This will be NULL, we initalised to Zero
  *outarg = StrDupA("Hello world"); // This is good enough for testing
  fprintf(stderr, "*outarg is now: %p\n", *outarg); // We can see this value by looking at our IntPtr instead of copying it
}
%}
```

With that in place we can run something like this successfully:

```
public class runme {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
        string blah;
        test.foobar(out blah);
        System.Console.WriteLine(blah);
  }
}
```

Which works as expected.

Comment: This is a very good start as this gives me the C#-Code as a result that I would expect. Unfortunately I'll get a mapping issue: "Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int/UInt must be paired with SysInt or SysUInt)." Not sure how to handle this. Would and could you help me again? Thank you!

Comment: I might be able to, but I'll have to find a Windows box and install visual studio so it'll take a while.

Comment: If I may help, let me know. We could have a look at my system together, if that helps. Thank you!

Comment: @TopperDEL I massively simplified the imtype typemap as most of it was left from the first idea I tried unsuccessfully and not actually needed. Part of it was definitely wrong and may have been connected to what you saw although I'm not totally sure as I've not got around to getting visual studio installed yet.

Comment: I understand - and I'm still very thankfull. I'm just not sure if my assumption is Right that I really get a string directly from the C-function. What if I get a pointer that Points to a string? I tried manually to get a Response, but failes with all I tried. I'm definitely no C-expert.
As stated above, the C-function gets generated by Go and the string-assignment in Go Looks like this:
"*cerr = C.CString("invalid apikey")"Maybe this helps you understand what I receive from C?

Comment: Pointer that points to string is what I did in my example - it looks like that matches what I was expecting. I'll try and dig into it some more at some point soon.

Comment: @TopperDEL - I had to make one minor change, but the latest version worked correctly with VS2017 when I tested it just now, excepting the fact that VS2017 doesn't believe `strdup` is actually a real function. I'd suggest trying to get what I've shown here building/running stand alone to try and understand what's not working right in your real project.

Comment: I get the string! Yeah! But it Exits with error on the line with 
                    global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tmpp1); Maybe this is not allowed as the Memory is allocated by the c-function?

Comment: It depends how you are allocating the memory for the string you returned - `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` is only legal and correct if it gets allocated by `LocalAlloc`, (which `StrDupA` does internally). If it comes from anywhere else you need to free it via the correct method for doing so. (At a guess from a quick skim of some docs that'd be `C.free` - you can make SWIG wrap that and then call this instead of `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` in the post part of the csin typemap).

Comment: Thank you so much, Flexo! I Need to find out more how it is allocated and if I Need to free it (what I suppose I have to). For the Moment it is ok how it is. Thank you! Would love to pay you a coffee for this!

Comment: @TopperDEL Do you please have a complete solution for this issue?

Comment: @mrdecompilator I'm sorry, I don't have a complete solution. My original issue got "closed" as the function got a different signature and I did not have problems with the new one. You may have a look here though, if that helps you: https://github.com/TopperDEL/uplink.net/blob/master/SWIG/storj_uplink_second.i